# How to pass multiple arguments to MVC Action through Ajax Function?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass two values to MVC controller as an argument.I know how to pass one but not sure about two.

Comment: Passing two parameters is no different than one. What problem are you actually encountering here? Are you getting errors? Is the data not being bound? It might help to post your action code here as well.

Comment: Ajax Call is not working at all.

Comment: Not working *how*?

Answer (score 0):

In `@Url.Action("Action_Name","Controller_Name")` , you have provided only one of the parameter and in data part please make sure that `parameter1` and `parameter2` have same name as that of your `GetRecord` action parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Verify").click(function () {
        var value1 = $('#txtBox1').val();
        var value2 = $('#txtBox2').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetRecord")" + "?parameter1=" + value1 + "&parameter2=" + value2,
            datatype: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log("Working");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a get in the action GetPassword ou GetRecord?